# AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) with multiple POST endpoints?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, visual-studio, asp.net-core

I am using Visual Studio 2022 to build an AWS Serverless Application Model (SAM) application, using `Functions.cs` to define multiple Lambda functions.

This application's Lambda functions will be consumed by external web applications.

Can I define multiple Lambda functions to handle different kinds of `POST` requests?  Or can I only have one function each for each HTTP verb (`POST`, `GET`, `PUT`, etc.)?

Below is a snippet from my `serverless.template` file (identifying information obfuscated) declaring my to `POST` functions.  Have I defined this correctly, or would I need to change something?

```
    "ListCertificates": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Architectures": [
      "x86_64"
    ],
    "Handler": "xxx.xxx.xxx.POC.AWS::xxx.xxx.xxx.POC.AWS.Functions::Post",
    "Runtime": "dotnet6",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "MemorySize": 256,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [
      "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    ],
    "Environment": {
      "Variables": {
        "POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME": "CertificateManagement",
        "POWERTOOLS_LOG_LEVEL": "Info",
        "POWERTOOLS_LOGGER_CASE": "PascalCase",
        "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_RESPONSE": true,
        "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_ERROR": true,
        "POWERTOOLS_METRICS_NAMESPACE": "ListCertificatesFunction"
      }
    },
    "Events": {
      "RootPost": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/",
          "Method": "POST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
},
"UploadCertificate": {
  "Type": "AWS::Serverless::Function",
  "Properties": {
    "Architectures": [
      "x86_64"
    ],
    "Handler": "xxx.xxx.xxx.POC.AWS::xxx.xxx.xxx.POC.AWS.Functions::Post",
    "Runtime": "dotnet6",
    "CodeUri": "",
    "MemorySize": 256,
    "Timeout": 30,
    "Role": null,
    "Policies": [
      "AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole"
    ],
    "Environment": {
      "Variables": {
        "POWERTOOLS_SERVICE_NAME": "CertificateManagement",
        "POWERTOOLS_LOG_LEVEL": "Info",
        "POWERTOOLS_LOGGER_CASE": "PascalCase",
        "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_RESPONSE": true,
        "POWERTOOLS_TRACER_CAPTURE_ERROR": true,
        "POWERTOOLS_METRICS_NAMESPACE": "UploadCertificateFunction"
      }
    },
    "Events": {
      "RootPost": {
        "Type": "Api",
        "Properties": {
          "Path": "/",
          "Method": "POST"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you using API Gateway and have you implemented your Lambda functions using .NET SDK?

Comment: @smac2000 yes to both

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my last comment - yes @smac2020 I am using the API Gateway and .NET SDK.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similiar .NET use case in the [AWS COde Library](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/what-is-code-library.html) that you should look at for this type of solution. It uses a client app (React), API Gateway to handle HTTP requests, and multiple AWS Lambda functions implemented by using AWS SDK for .NET. The Lambda functions invoke various AWS Sercices such as S3.

It is an AWS Serverless solution and you'll gain a deeper understanding of this type of solution by going though it.

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/dynamodb_example_cross_PAM_section.html)